# Why change the ordering of the tables in the FROM clause makes the SQL execution time different?

Tags: sql, oracle

Edit: I don't know why the hate for this question but maybe its because of the confusion about my question. I purposely used `/*+ ORDERED */` to control the order of execution and changes the ordering of the tables in the `FROM` clause. I was wondering WHY the execution time can change. Is it because of the join order? is it because of the table size? Hope this clears out the confusion.

So I was just playing around SQL queries and realized the following: If I change the ordering of tables in the FROM clause, the execution time can be very different. The following query runs in about 0.966 sec. But if I move `OrderDetails d` to the last of the `FROM` clause, the execution is only 0.573 sec! Any reason behind this? I was using ORACLE SQL Developer

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */
    su.CompanyName, CategoryName, ProductName, c.CompanyName, c.country,
    FirstName, LastName, Quantity, d.UnitPrice, sh.CompanyName
FROM 
    OrderDetails d, Suppliers su, Shippers sh, Categories t, Products p,
    Employees e, Customers c, orders o
WHERE 
    t.CategoryID = p.CategoryID 
    AND c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
    AND e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID 
    AND o.OrderID = d.OrderID 
    AND p.ProductID = d.ProductID 
    AND sh.ShipperID = o.ShipVia 
    AND su.SupplierID = p.SupplierID 
    AND LOWER(ProductName) Like '%lager%' 
    AND LOWER(c.city) IN ('vancouver', 'london', 'charleroi', 'cunewalde') 
    AND d.Quantity BETWEEN 5 AND 100 
    AND (RequiredDate-ShippedDate > 10)
ORDER BY 
    c.CompanyName;
```

Comment: re-ordering the tables in the FROM clause should not make any difference...

Comment: @MitchWheat Did you try? I ran the queries and the execution time are different!

Comment: I didn't need to try. That's not how it works.

Comment: @MitchWheat https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B91BFEF62EF3E6B%211120

Comment: @MitchWheat page 3 and page 5 of the pdf file. Shows different elapsed time. I timed with SET TIMING ON and 
SET AUTOTRACE ON  command

Comment: Run it both ways several times. It's likely that the first time you ran it, some portion of the data wasn't cached in memory, whereas the second time you ran it, it all was (because you had just run a query that wanted the same data). To get a **true** test of the speed, clear your cached data & execution plans before each execution (but don't do this on a production database, obviously).

Comment: @alroc I did some search online it looks might be because of the join sequence. But I cannot explain the reason. Still looking for a good answer

Comment: Normally the optimizer would choose the best order in which to process the query but because you are using the `ordered` hint (in Oracle) this will force the optimizer to process the query in the exact table order as you've written the query, which may or may not be the best plan. How quickly does the query run without the hint? The reason changing the order of the tables in the from clause is having an impact is because you are using a hint that is telling the query to run in the order that it's written, without deciding for itself what order to take (based on table stats).

Comment: @BrianDeMilia yes. that is why i used the 'ordered' hint because i want to manually control the order of process and see why the execution time can be different by  simply change the ordering of tables in the FROM clause

Comment: ?? You put in an `ordered` hint then ask why the table order makes any difference???? It might've helped to tag Oracle too.

Comment: The optimizer should be choosing the fastest approach. Are the stats of each table up to date? Check their `last analyzed` date in the `dba_tables` or `all_tables` dictionaries. If the stats are out of date trying updating them and then re-running without the hint to see if it chooses the appropriate plan. Generally you should not need to use this hint. If it still chooses a disadvantageous plan then you can stick with the hint and specifying smaller tables first, although they would only be beneficial if the other tables can be filtered based on those smaller tables.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia i checked the size of the tables. Some tables are small some are large. If the query execute the large table join first then it could takes longer time? Could this be one possible reason?

Comment: How long has it been since the tables were analyzed (check `last_analyzed`)? The stats may be out of date. The optimizer uses those stats when deciding on what order to process the query. If they are out of date it could negatively influence the optimizer's decisions. With the `ordered` hint, yes, if your tables and joins are listed in such a way that smaller tables are accessed first and have their rows filtered in on first, and the larger tables that follow can be more directly accessed based on values in the smaller tables already established, you can potentially see a performance gain.

Comment: Question amounts to: "I did something to make a difference. Why did it make a difference?" and the answer is because you did something that made that difference!!!!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The "hate" (?) is probably because you don't seem to be picking up on the cause of the issue - you've added a hint which forces Oracle to *not* optimise the join order, so unless you want a primer on how the CBO works, your question has been answered. Hints like "ORDERED" should only be used when you already understand what it's for and why exactly you're using it. If you're not sure why you're adding the hint, you should remove it.

Answer (score 5):

Uh, you are specifying the `ordered` hint.  As described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm):

> The ORDERED hint causes Oracle to join tables in the order in which
>   they appear in the FROM clause.

Usually, the Oracle (or any other optimizer) finds an optimal ordering for the `join`s, so the ordering in the `from` clause does not matter. But with the `ordered` hint, you are specifying the order of the joins.  Hence, changing the order of tables in the `from` clause can have a big impact on execution.

By the way, you should learn to use modern, explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Yes. I useD the ORDERED hint because i want to know why the execution time are different by simply changing the ordering of tables in the FROM clause. But your answer is not what I asked in my question

Comment: @taimeili123 . . . It is because you are using the `ordered` hint.  Let the optimizer do the job and remove the hint.  You are aware that when joining multiple tables, the ordering of the joins does have an impact on performance.  That is one of the key things that optimizers do.

Comment: Because it forces a change to the query plan, and if you read the answer by @dimm; if you happen to force those tables in an  order that cannot efficiently utilise a nested loop, it will use a slower hash join instead. If you don't use the ordered hint, the order doesn't matter. If you do, the order does matter, and you have to look at the query plan to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You have a + ORDERED optimizer hint.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5555

> The ORDERED hint causes Oracle to join tables in the order in which they appear in the FROM clause.

For fully understanding the matter I would recommend reading a database book, especially chapter for algorithms for searching and joining and chapter for query optimizations.

For example, in the nested loop join algorithm we put the larger table in the outer loop and the smaller in the inner loop. That way we get less disk accesses.

The outer loop loads same data only once, and the inner loads the same data multiple times. That's why we iterate the larger table in the outer loop.